# How do I know if the power series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty{n(1-2^{-n})z^n}$ is convergent when $|z|=R$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, power-series

How do I know if the following power series is convergent when $|z|=R$, where R is the radius of convergence.
I know that the power series is convergent when $|z-a|<R$ and divergent when $|z-a|>R$
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty{n(1-2^{-n})z^n}
$$
The radius of convergence is $R=1$, so we have that
$$|z|=1$$

Thanks in advance

Comment: In any case, for $z=1$, it diverges trivially.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This follows directly from the theorem

> If $\sum a_n$ converges, then $a_n \to 0$.

For any $|z|=1$, we can show $$\left|n(1-2^{-n})z^n\right| = n(1-2^{-n}) \to \infty,$$ so in particular $n(1-2^{-n})z^n \not\to 0$, so it diverges for all $|z|=1$.

Comment: okay, that makes sense. What if we had the power series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty{n(1-3^{-n})z^{2n}}$

Comment: @TarekBadr: Same thing.. the radius of convergence of your series is one too.

Comment: @Oliver Diaz so there is no difference when working with odd and even numbers?

Comment: @TarekBadr:The radius of convergence of your series is $\limsup_n\sqrt[2n]{n(1-3^{-n})}=1$. If $|z|=1$, $\lim_n(n(1-3^{-n})|z^{2n}|)\neq0$.